# Cannot access network share from only one PC

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share, windows-authentication, netapp

It's a strange problem. I'm very confused. In my Test Lab, I have configured NetApp virtual storage appliance and configured shares. This NetApp appliance is connected to domain and any domain user can authenticate to access shares. Only only one server running windows server 2008 cannot access this appliance. However, it can access any other share on the network.

This is the error when trying to access NetApp storage.

[image: Network Access Error]

I have recorded the issue and uploaded to youtube. Kindly watch the video for better understanding of the issue and give me suggestions.

[Youtube Video Link](https://youtu.be/92UCgT5rR38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem started because I previously added AllowInsecureGuestAuth DWORD entry into the registry and forgot about it.

This [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/887429) made me check the registry. I removed AllowInsecureGuestAuth and made entries to the below parameters. The system can now successfully connect to storage. Screenshot below for current registry settings.

[image: Registry Entries]

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters

Value Name: EnableSecuritySignature
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters

Value Name: RequireSecuritySignature
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 0

Answer (score 0):

need to change the value to AllowInsecureGuestAuth in regedit to resolve the issue

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/the-account-is-not-authorized-to-login-from-this/5aa0c61d-7e27-41ce-b1cd-1bedbe5c5ead

Comment: I removed the AllowInsecureGuestAuth entry as it is not in the registry by default.